# How do I use "scribbling" to detect mods to free blocks?

Tags: memory-management, exc-bad-access

**I'm trying to figure out what's corrupting my heap**; I'm sure you envy me and my predicament.

**SO tells me that I can turn on "Scribble" to write `0xAA` into allocs and `0x55` into deallocs, to help me figure out where things are going wrong.**

Only thing is, I've got no clue where/how to make good use of this. **What do I use this *for*?**

(Bonus: I'm curious about why those values, specifically, are used...)

I'm coding C/C++ in Xcode using openFrameworks and the Vamp psychoacoustic-labeling library, for what it's worth, but I think my question is more general than that.

Comment: Some objection to the macosx native malloc debugger or valgrind (if it's currently operational there)?

Comment: Huh? Sorry, I don't think I'm up to the level where I can parse that. Could you spell it out a little more loudly and clearly?

Comment: I've set `MallocGuardEdges` and `MallocCheckHeapStart/Each` but don't see any changes in behavior. I assume I'm then supposed to do something in `gdb` to make use of these changes in `malloc`?

Answer (score -1):

1. run 'man Guard_Malloc' or 'man libgmalloc' and read about the debugging options.
2. see valgrind, perhaps starting from http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html

Comment: Valgrind looks very powerful; right now it's giving me tons of errors from library code. I'll try to sort it out though.

Comment: got "No manual entry for gmalloc" on my machine, [nothing from Google either](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp#hl=en&safe=off&sa=X&ei=XvHkTcaAEYOW8QOt0tSHBw&ved=0CBoQvgUoAA&q=%22man+gmalloc%22&nfpr=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4cb0eeca208f72b3&biw=1594&bih=934)... help?

Comment: @icky oops, once more with feeling.